# Mixing a4 and a3 in one Latex file

Tags: latex, geometry

I am finishing my thesis and have a large appendix. Some tables only look good, if first done on a3 and then (paper)printed on a4. Anyhow, working all the files seperalty is fine, but I struggle to compile all in one.

I use the geometry package and start the document with:

```
\usepackage[a4paper,left=30mm,right=20mm,top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
```

For the appendix, I want to include the table and use

```
\newgeometry{a3paper,left=25mm,right=15mm, top=15mm, bottom=15mm}
```

However, the command is completely ignored and I can read "a3paper,left=25mm,right=15mm, top=15mm, bottom=15mm" above the table.

What did I miss? Is it even possible? If not, how do I get the numbers right, if I have to include it as a pdf (which works)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible (at least if your output is DVI). Have a look at [Change paper size in the middle of a latex document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812892/change-paper-size-in-the-middle-of-a-latex-document).

Comment: Thanks, it is supposed to be a normal PDF - whichever compiler, I would use it...

Comment: Okay, I tried and played. I get the large papersize, but my geometry is still applied to a4...
\eject \pdfpagewidth=11in \pdfpageheight=17in
\newgeometry{left=25mm,right=15mm, top=15mm, bottom=15mm}